# Rails: Polymorphic Associations - Create Child In Form And Choose Parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails

To illustrate my question, i'll use the following association as listed on ruby guides for polymorphic associations:

```
class Picture < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end

class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
end
```

Now in our `:pictures` table, we will have 2 different columns, namely `imageable_id` and `imageable_type`.

The first thing that I am unclear of is, what exactly goes into `imageable_type` ? Is that something that the "rails magic" would automatically fill up when `imageable_id` is declared?

Moving on to my next point (which will probably indirectly answer my uncertainty above), how do I assign either a `Product` or `Employee` to my `Picture.new` form?

```
#create new picture form
#assume pre_created_array holds the :id for both Employee & Product
<%= form_for @picture do |f| %>
  #relevant fields ontop
  #choosing parent field is the one im unsure of      
  #this is what i assumed might be correct(?)
  <%= f.select :imageable_id, options_for_select(pre_created_array) %>
<% end %>
```

Now does this form actually work? Is the building of the association something that has to be handled in the controller action instead? I am actually not very sure because usually in a regular association the parent can be declared before `.save`, such as doing `@post.employee = #find an employee`. So are we suppose to read the `:imageable_id`?

```
#pictures controller

def create
  @picture = Picture.new(picture_params)
  #manipulate :imageable_id here???
  if @picture.save
    #blahblah other code
end
```

So i am actually quite unsure about this, whether it is supposed to be the form or controller handling the building of association. Which is why i'm bringing up this 2 "uncertainties".

Answer (score 1):

A polymorphic association is cool because it allows a single table to `belong_to` multiple, as you know. So given a `picture`, we don't have to know whether it belongs to an `employee` or a `product`, we can just call `picture.imageable` and get the parent.

So if **we** don't have to know where the parent is, that must means **Rails** has to know. How does it know? `imageable_type`! `imageable_type` is the name of the class which it belongs to. In this case, either `'Employee'` or `'Product'`. That way, given the `imageable_id`, it knows what table in which to search.

`image.imageable` actually calls `image.imageable_type.constantize.find(image.imageable_id)`

Rails will do this "magic" for you if you simply assign objects instead of IDs. `image.update(imageable: Product.first)` will assign both for you.

So in your form, you should be able work with a collection of objects and let Rails do the rest for you.